# How can I use matplotlib divider to split a subplot into more than two parts?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've generated an image containing 4 subplots (globe, indian, pacific and atlantic) using gridspec:

```
    from matplotlib import gridspec

    fig = plt.figure()
    gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
```

Each of those subplots then uses a divider so that I can use a different vertical scale for the shallow and deep ocean:

```
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

    axMain = plt.subplot(gs[0])
    plt.sca(axMain)
    cf = axMain.contourf(...)

    divider = make_axes_locatable(axMain)
    axShallow = divider.append_axes("top", size="100%", pad=0.1, sharex=axMain)
    axShallow.contourf(...)
```

[image]

I want to add an extra line graph to the top of each subplot (i.e. a third plot on top of the other two), showing the integrated value for each latitude over the entire 2000m depth of the plot (i.e. this third plot would share the x-axis of the other two below it).

I can't figure out how to divide each subplot for a third time, so I was hoping someone could suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dividing the axes several times using `make_axes_locatable` is perfectly possible. You just need to call `divider.append_axes(..)` a second (or third etc.) time.
Here is an example.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

fig = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,100, num=101), np.linspace(0,100, num=101))
f = lambda x, y: np.sin(x/10.)+y/100.


axMain = plt.subplot(gs[0])
plt.sca(axMain)
cf = axMain.contourf(X[0:40,:], Y[0:40,:], f(X,Y)[0:40,:] , vmin=-1, vmax=2)

divider = make_axes_locatable(axMain)
axShallow = divider.append_axes("top", size="100%", pad=0.1, sharex=axMain)
axShallow.contourf(X[41:80,:], Y[41:80,:], f(X,Y)[41:80,:], vmin=-1, vmax=2)
axShallow.set_xticklabels([])
axShallow2 = divider.append_axes("top", size="50%", pad=0.1, sharex=axMain)
axShallow2.contourf(X[81:,:], Y[81:,:], f(X,Y)[81:,:], vmin=-1, vmax=2)
axShallow2.set_xticklabels([])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you! It turns out my problem was that I was trying to define a second divider (i.e. divider = make_axes_locatable(axShallow)) when I needed to just use the original one. This became obvious once you posted your example.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful!